# Is there Python Class instance have an attribute to get the class name?

Tags: python, class

I have below Python code:

```
class Shape(object):

    def draw(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Triangle(Shape):

    def draw(self):
        print("draw triangle")

class Square(Shape):

    def draw(self):
        print("draw square")

t = Triangle()
```

I want to get the instance `t`'s class's name(string).

How can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instance.__class__.__name__` to get the class name:

```
t = Triangle()

print(t.__class__.__name__)
```